# Get 'ref' of a Child of Route React Element

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I try to access to a ref of a child of a Route element of react router but it doesn't work.

```
<Route path={path} render={ () => (
            <Child ref={ (el => this.$child = el)} />
          )} />
```

Console log: `"Warning: Stateless function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail."`

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to get the `ref` of Child component even though it's inside Route element. The problem here is your Child element is probably a stateless function component which doesn't support ref. Because functional components don't have instances.

Define your Child component as an ES6 class instead of a function.

You can read about this more here:https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#refs-and-functional-components

Comment: Thanks ! The probleme was that my Child was "export default withRouter(Child)" and not just a simple class !

Comment: This answer is quite stale as React functional components support refs, there is nothing that blocks that in general, albeit depending on implementation, some specific functional components might not. But the general answer to use class-based components isnt correct anymore.